# Написать скрипт, который будет заменять у всех картинок в src .svg на .png JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, img, скрипт, замена

Пишу костыль для Edge и IE, но в JS мало что понимаю, поэтому и не получается фокус.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  if (~images[i].src.indexOf("svg")) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = images[i].src;
    img.src = img.src.replace(/.svg/i, ".png");
    img.onload = function(){
    console.log("Получилось! " + img.src + " " + images[i].src + " " + i);
      images[i].src = img.src + "?" + new Date().getTime();
    };
    img = null;
  }
}
```

Вот только ничего не получается: src не меняется. Что я сделал не так и как мне быть 
PHP, AJAX, JQ использовать крайне не рекомендуется

Этот скрипт подключается, если у пользователя IE или Edge в этом участке кода

```
        function loadingInProgress() {

            loaderProgress.seek(Math.round(loading_progress * 10));

            if (loading_progress < 100) {
                requestAnimationFrame(loadingInProgress);
            } else {
                logo.className += ' complete';
                $("DIV.preloader_overlay").delay(1200).fadeOut('slow');

                BrowserDetect.init();
                if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" || BrowserDetect.browser == "MS Edge") {
                  // alert("Вы идиот, если используете этот браузер");
                  include("js/iefix.js");
                }
            }
        }

        loadingInProgress();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру заменяем все `.svg` на `.jpg`.

```css
img {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/article_small/public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.svg">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.svg">

<script defer>
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); // Получаем все <img>
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var old = imgs[i].src; // Получаем стаоре значение
    var newest = old.replace(/.svg/, '.jpg'); // Делаем замену .svg => .jpg
    imgs[i].src = newest; // Заменяем на новое значение
  }
</script>
```

*P.S. Работает в Egde, IE6+*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как мне это прикрутить к сайту? Код должен выполнится до загрузки страницы и без участия пользователя (без нажатий на кнопку)

Comment: @Nitayd, обновил. Атрибут **defer** откладывает выполнение скрипта до тех пор, пока вся страница не будет загружена полностью. Но лучше положить скрипт после DOM-элементов, чтобы наверняка :))

Comment: Вы просто бог!!! Спасибо огромное, заменили мне 100 строчные непонятные скрипты на пару строк :)
Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Nitayd, рад помочь:)))